# MVC approach with C++

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have been learning PHP MVC pattern and it is pretty cool. have almost finished app and I can see how mess you can make a code without good design.
Now can MCV be applied to C++ apps? Where does Plugin manager/Plugins go if that is even possible?In model or controller?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I mean C++ with GUI toolkit like QT/Wxwidgets/GTK+
Also Please help me on how to implement in C++. I have learned how to do it in PHP but as you know the two languages are somehow different!

**EDIT2**

http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30983

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> how do you actually implement it in C++

- make classes in charge of rendering know nothing about application details. Call them SomethingView classes to make this point clear
- make your domain objects not know anything about visualization or user interaction. You don't need to call them Model, but you could
- create a set of classes in charge of running the role of Controllers: wire somehow dependencies to view and model classes via dependency injection if possible. example: [CppInject](https://github.com/admiyo/CppInject). In any case, controller classes can know both about model and view classes, so the important part is this: **all the coupling between view and model objects is isolated to the controllers**.
- Also, this implies, that all imperative-style programming should be confined to the controller classes as well: view and model should be declarative-style. That means, they should **offer services related to its role, but avoid direct interaction with other objects as side-effects**
- It is not true you need to implement communication between controllers and the other components with event-style system, although such system is definitely helpful, but certainly not required
- *surprise!* the above applies to any language or framework, except of course languages that somehow already force MVC down your throat from the start, i.e: ruby on rails

Comment: Isn't this approach more like the MVP pattern? In MVC the view and model know about each other. The model notifies the view and the view pulls the data to show directly from the model. In MVP it is described as above, where the model and the view don't know about each other and the presenter does the couling.

Comment: "surprise! the above applies to any language or framework" yes and no, a lot of toolkits have some way of doing MVC / MVP half baked in, for instance in Qt widgets have both view and controller responsibility. You can aggregate widgets in UIs that are expressed in XML but then the new widget also has both roles (displaying and handlin user input).

Answer (score 13):

MVC is a design pattern not a language specific construct, So yes you can apply it to C++ app as well.

MVC can and should be applied in any language so your User Interface is loosely coupled with the backend & either can be changed with minimum impact on each other.

The MVC pattern provides a clean separation of objects into:

- **Models** for maintaining data,
- **Views** for displaying all or a portion of the data, and
- **Controllers** for handling events that affect the model or view(s).

Comment: Could you explain little bit on Models?
Will I be right to say that Model==>DB Queries(fetch data), Controllers==>react to Events and View==> GUI functionalities?

Comment: @Stefano: Have a look at the link in the answer, It has an good practical example (independent of any language) so that will give you an better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, MVC can be applied in C++. For example, the MFC framework uses Document/View architecture which is essentially an MVC.

A design pattern isn't a library or class. It's a pattern. So you don't have a generic MVC library  for C++.

Comment: @Stefano: In order to do MVC in C++ you need to know C++ and understand MVC - nothing more. So, learn C++ and read about MVC

Comment: @Stefano And of course you need a concrete C++ GUI library, which you have to understand, too, of course.

Comment: I have pretty solid understanding of wxWidgets. In fact I use it in my latest C++ project

Answer (score 5):

Use [Tree frogs Framework](http://www.treefrogframework.org/). TreeFrog Framework is a high-speed and full-stack C++ framework for developing Web applications.

Answer (score 3):

[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is an architectural design pattern (i.e. a *way* of building software) commonly associated with web applications, but it is applicable in general to any software project in any language. You have to make a little abstraction effort on your project, and identify which piece of software belongs to each part (i.e. a GUI is probably part of View, etc.).

Note that this type of pattern is mainly aimed to *separate developement*, so that any part of the project can be developed regardless of the others. This can be annoying for a small standalone application, but useful and rewarding on bigger projects.

Comment: Thanks! Now remaining question is, how do you actually implement it in C++

Comment: The wikipedia entry suggests a bunch of either GUI or web application frameworks fo C++ built around the concept of MVC. But MVC is actually a *pattern*, not a particular library, so you are free to use it as an inpiration for creating your own application.

Comment: Anyway, if you learned MVC in PHP you probably wrote some web application, so I suggest you learn the other part and try to write a C++ application with a GUI.

Comment: the problem is tutorial. Iama looking the link below by Als

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I use boost state machines for the logical and boost signals to connect things together.

I wrote a little example that you can analyze here:
https://github.com/edubois/mvp-player

Comment: Can you improve the answer by adding some snippets of your code here?